# Help with updating vb.net formview using storedprocedure

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have followed this tutorial for the most part to explain what I am doing. http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/creating-a-business-logic-layer-vb

What i need to do is figure out the best way to approach to be able to update my formview. I do not understand what the tutorial is trying to explain to me so i tried it the way i have updated a gridview before. But I am receiving "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." I tried to debug and view the callstack but it does not really tell me much.

I have my sql stored procedure to update which when executed works fine.

---

I also have another class in which i reference the application details class

applicant.vb

This is the code in order for when you click the view details link on the gridview it passes you off to another page that shows that applicants details it is within the same applicant.vb class

I am trying to update using the following method on the .aspx page but i receive the following error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Memberdetails.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing which line of code is causing that error, I can't say for sure, however, my guess is that your error is on this line of code.

> _applicantadapter = New applicantTableAdapter

Put an open parentheses after applicantTableAdapter to see the different constructor signatures available to you for that type.  I bet you'll see none of the options allow no parameters.

That error means that the object type you are trying to instantiate requires that you include parameter(s) (and you are not).

Comment: Thanks for the response that did not help. In my case the table adapter is strictly populating the form by the pappid. Also i thought i was supplying the parameters in my code above under applicant.vb

Comment: So are you saying you figured it out?

Comment: I know my question is probably too confusing without actually seeing what I am doing Thanks any how for the help I am trying to take the approach the tutorial took and if i have any more questions will open a new ticket Thanks Again